# Does joint probability apply when calculating likelihood with the binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood

I am trying to understand this picture from [Statquest](https://youtube.com/watch?v=4KKV9yZCoM4)

[image: Likelihood of p = 0.25]

in the light of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Likelihood_function_of_a_parameterized_model) statement that Likelihood

> describes the joint probability of the observed data as a function of
> the parameters of the chosen statistical model.

Am I right thinking "joint probability" does not apply here since we only have 1 dimension, being X?

I am also confused here about what it means to have

> a likelihood of p = 0.25 when p = 0.5

surely p cant be both?

Comment: It is a joint probability over *all observations*. For the image, it is the joint probability of 4 choosing orange and 3 choosing grape. That joint probability varies with possible values of p: 0.273 for p = 0.5, and 0.058 for p = 0.25.

Comment: Thank you. So are there 7 observations here? Does "joint" refer to grape and orange (the 2 possibilities) or the number of cans?

Comment: Yes, there are 7 observations in the graphic. Since one would not be concerned with the specific sequence in which the observations were made, the 7 observations are summarized as "4 chose orange, and 3 chose grape", or, equivalently, "4 out of 7 chose orange over grape". For a given value for p, the joint probability of those 7 observations is given by the binomial distribution with x = 4 and n = 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood *function* $L(p; n, x)$ is $L(p; n, x) = \binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ which, *regarded as a function of $p$*, has value $0.058$ when $n$ and $x$ happen to equal $7$ and $4$ respectively, that is, $L(0.25 \mid 7, 4) = 0.058$ as claimed in the picture you have included.  The statement that puzzles you is *not* what you quote from the picture: it is a *mangling* of what is actually said in the picture, *viz.*,

"is less than $0.273$, the likelihood when $p=0.5$."

What the statement is claiming is that $L(0.25; 7, 4) = 0.058$ is a smaller number than $L(0.5; 7, 4) = 0.273$ which everyone will agree with, I hope. It *does not* say "a likelihood of $p=0.25$ when $p=0.5$" as you think it does.

In short, *inferring* (and claiming in print advertisements and TV commercials) that $3$ of $4$ dentists recommend Grape Fanta over Orange Fanta when recommending a Fanta flavor to their patients who drink Fanta when the evidence is that $4$ out of $7$ dentists actually surveyed chose Orange Fanta over Grape Fanta is a serious mis-representation of the data and likely to bring condemnation from the readers of stats.SE and maybe even the Advertising Council and the FTC. As the picture says, claiming that dentists are actually equally divided between Orange and Grade Fanta is better since $L(0.5) > L(0.25)$.

Exercise:  Show that $L(p; 7,4)$, regarded as a function of $p \in [0,1]$, attains maximum value at $p = \frac 47 = 0.571428\ldots$

Turning to  "Likelihood describes the joint probability of the observed data as a function of the parameters of the chosen statistical model"

the joint probability here is the probability that $4$ of the $7$ dentists preferred Orange Fanta while the other three preferred Grape Fanta. This joint probability is the sum of the probabilities of the $35 = \binom{7}{4}$ *vectors* of $7$ possible answers ($7$-tuples if you prefer that name over vectors) that might be obtained when $4$ out of $7$ dentists say that they prefer Orange Fanta over Grape Fanta and $3$ have the opposite preference.  The possible vectors of $7$ answers are
\begin{align}
&(O,O,O,O, G, G, G)\\
&(O,O,O,G, O, G, G)\\
&(O,O,O,G, G, O, G)\\
&(O,O,O,G, G, G, O)\\
&(O,O,G,O, O, G, G)\\
&(O,O,G,O, G, O, G)\\
&(O,O,G,O, G, G, O)\\
&\text{and so on till the $35$-th item}\\
&(G,G,G, O, O, O, O)
\end{align}
Each vector has probability $p^4(1-p)^3$ (hidden assumption: the dentist preferences are *independent* and each dentist has probability $p$ of preferring Orange Fanta over Grape Fanta) giving that the _joint probability that $4$ of $7$ dentists prefer Orange Fanta over Grape Fanta is $\binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3 = 35p^4(1-p)^3$.  How come we can just *add up* these $35$ probabilities? Well, if one specific vector of answers is observed, we are automatically *excluding* all other $34$ vectors of answers as possible: these are *disjoint* (a.k.a. *mutually exclusive*) events and so the probability that *some* one of these $35$ vectors (we don't care *which one*) was observed (i.e. *some* $4$ out of the $7$ dentists asked  preferred Orange Fanta over Grape Fanta) is $\binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3 = 35p^4(1-p)^3$.  For each $p \in [0,1]$, the *likelihood function* (regarded as a function of $p$, with $n$ and $x$ as parameters), has value *equal* to the *joint probability* of the observations given the parameters. Thus,  $L(p; 7, 4) = \binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion about the wording. I also asked about how joint probability applies here. Should that be a separate question?

Comment: Thank you for the joint probability update.  However looking at Wikipedia, a joint probability distribution involves two random variables. Surely we have only one here? that is X?  Only X is mentioned in the Likelihood equation?  Or is the other RV implied somehow as N-X?  From your answer I guess it must be ... but surely N-X is not an RV indepentant of X?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution

Comment: @Kirsten Repeat as often as needed till you have memorized it:  "X is not a random variable".  There are 7 _independent_ random variables representing the 7 answers; these random variables take on value Orange with (unknown) probability $p$ and value Grape with probability $1-p$. 4 of the answers are known to have value Orange and 3 to have value Grape.  _Before asking for the choices_, we _know_ that the **joint probability** that 4 of these 7 random variables will have value Orange and 3 will have value Grape is $\binom 74p^4(1-p)^3$. Repeat again:  "X is not a random variable".

Comment: Thank you, but why is X not an RV? It looks like a "numerical description of the outcome of a statistical experiment." (though I now appreciate that the independent RVs in this problem must be the binary drink outcome ) https://www.britannica.com/science/statistics/Random-variables-and-probability-distributions

Comment: @Kirsten Well, yes, $X$ is indeed a binomial random variable, but you are insisting on finding a _joint_ distribution of $X$ and some other random variable. The outcomes of the experiment (the data) are the 7 answers and the joint distributions that you ought to be seeking are the joint distribution of the 7 answers, and not the joint distribution with something else.

Comment: So in summary, X is a Binomial RV and the 7 joint RVs are Bernoulli  RVs.?